# How do I find the first occurrence of "&" in a string using regex?

Tags: regex, rpa

I have a set of data and each row has different number of &. How do I find and match the first & in each row using regex?

Sample data:

1. Document **&** saved (faulty authorization)
2. Document **&** cannot be processed in this transaction with billing type &
3. Revenue of leading WBS element **&** determined by substitution from &

I am working on a RPA system and when I put & as regex, it matches all & occurrences instead of the first.

So wonder if you guys have any alternatives.

Thanks!

Comment: Why doesn't `/&/` work?

Comment: in the RPA system that I am using, when I put & it matches all & that appear in the string. So I wonder if there is another way to find the &

Comment: This is *crucial information* that you didn't include.

Comment: oks thanks for telling me . I have edited the question.

Comment: So, what is the regex you tried that you have trouble with? In order to have *have any alternatives*, we need to know where you stand.

Comment: I tried with /&/. It works in https://regex101.com. But when I put it in my RPA system, it matches all & in the string.

Comment: So, tried anything else? `\A[^&]*\K&`, for example? Or `(?<=\A[^&]*)&`?

Comment: Is it possible to disable global flag `/g`? Or use capture groups like `/(&).*/`?

Comment: (?<=\A[^&]*)& works! Thank you so much

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)) as you are entitled to the upvoting privilege after reaching 15 rep points. Note you may upvote all the answers that turned out helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the regex engine you are using is .NET, you may use a positive lookbehind based solution:

```
(?<=\A[^&]*)&
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5CA%5B%5E%26%5D*%29%26&i=Abc%20sdef%0D%0Ag%20h%20%26i%20%20%26%20and%0D%0Amore%20text%26).

**Details**

- `(?<=\A[^&]*)` - a location in the string that is immediately preceded with

  - `\A` - start of string
  - `[^&]*` - 0 or more chars other than `&`
- `&` - a `&` char.